# Sorting in the hazelcast java

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm trying to sort hazelcast value field.

```
final HazelcastInstance instance1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IMap<Integer, String> map = instance1.getMap("map");

        map.put(10, "B");
        map.put(9, "A");
        map.put(8, "C");

        PagingPredicate<Integer, String> predicate = new PagingPredicate<Integer, String>(new TruePredicate(), map.size());
        Collection<String> values = map.values(predicate);
        for (Object value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

this gives me the result in sorted list like `A,B,C`

In the same way how to sort the HazelcastjsonValue by passing the json key

example:-

```
IMap<Integer, HazelcastJsonValue> map = instance1.getMap("map");

        String json1 = "{\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"D\"\r\n" + "}";
        String json2 = "{\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"A\"\r\n" + "}";
        String json3 = "{\r\n" + "  \"name\": \"C\"\r\n" + "}";
        map.put(10, new HazelcastJsonValue(json1));
        map.put(9, new HazelcastJsonValue(json2));
        map.put(8, new HazelcastJsonValue(json3));

      //SqlPredicate predicate = new SqlPredicate("name");
        PagingPredicate<Integer, String> predicate = new PagingPredicate<Integer, String>(new TruePredicate(),
                map.size());
        Collection<HazelcastJsonValue> values = map.values(predicate);
        for (Object value : values) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```

Comment: How does your output "A,B,C" related to your first code snippet? I can't see a "B" anywhere?

Comment: I have edited the question. please check

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242232/sort-the-hazelcast-json-value-in-java/64258279#64258279