# Sort the Hazelcast json value in java

Tags: java, sorting, hazelcast

I'm storing the Hazelcast JSON value in IMAP

```
IMap.put(Integer,new HazelcastjsonValue("{"id":"001","name":"vikram"}"));
IMap.put(Integer,new HazelcastjsonValue("{"id":"002","name":"abhishek"}"));
```

How to sort the HazelcastjsonValue by `name`

I know using paging predicate we can achieve a sorted JSON array.

But how to use the paging predicate for the HazelcastjsonValue.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can set an index as described in [Hazelcast Reference Manual: Indexing Queries](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#indexing-queries). In your case, it would look like:

```
IMap.addIndex(new IndexConfig(IndexType.SORTED, "name"));
```

Then, the result collection should be sorted.

If you don't want to set an index, then I guess you can use `Predicates.pagingPredicate(comparator, size)`, but you would need write your own custom comparator.